# Http post using AsyncTask and NameValuePairs

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I have an app that needs to send some data to the server. I create a Connection class to handle the process. Below is my code:

```
private class Connection extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<NameValuePair>, Void, Void>{

    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... nameValuePairs){

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xxxx.com/postdata.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

         // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }
        finally{}

    }

}
```

However, I get the following error: "The constructor UrlEncodedFormEntity(ArrayList[]) is undefined". I'm new to Android and I have no idea what's causing the error. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class Connection extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<NameValuePair>, Void, Void>{

    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... nameValuePairs){
        // get zero index of nameValuePairs and use that to post
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvPairs = nameValuePairs[0];

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xxxx.com/postdata.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPairs));

         // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }
        finally{}

    }

}
```